# How to turn a list (of size one) into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and within the dictionaries there are dictionaries, and within those dictionaries, there are lists as values - within those lists is the information I need to access.

I want to turn the lists into dictionaries. The entire list of dictionaries are set up like this:

```
data = [{'date': 'Aug 1 1980', 
       'hour': '2PM', 
       'group': {'location' : 
                  [{'country': 'United States', 
                  'state': 'Utah', 
                  'city': 'St. George', 
                  'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}]},
        {'date': 'Aug 1 1980', 
        'hour': '4PM', 
        'group': {'location' : 
                   [{'country': 'United States', 
                   'state': 'Utah', 
                   'city': 'St. George', 
                   'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}]}]
```

I need the the coordinates but the type of location is a list. How can I turn this list into a dictionary? Should I start by splitting by ':' and ','s into keys and values? That seems like an awful way to do it and I'm hoping someone can help me with a better, quicker way.

*Edit*
I would want my dictionary to look like this:

```
{'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Utah', 'city' :'St George', 'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}
```

Comment: Splitting is for processing strings, not dictionaries and lists.

Comment: Right, I would have to turn it into a string, split it, read those into a dictionary... which seems really dumb and painstakingly long to do so I would greatly appreciate a better way.

Comment: What would be the desired result of this process applied to your example list?

Comment: What should the keys of the dictionary be? It seems like you should be able to do this with a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Why would you turn it into a string instead of just looping over the list?

Comment: `coords = container['location'][0]['coordinates']` would retrieve the coordinates and `dct = container['location'][0]` would be the whole dictionary.

Comment: What do you want if there's more than one dictionary in the list?

Comment: @martineau Right now the entire entry under location is just one long list entry so I can't separate by 'coordinates' - that's what I need to do

Comment: I know what it is and what I suggested will get the value associated with the `'coordinates'` key in the first dictionary in the list (or the entire first and only dictionary, if that's what you want).

Comment: @martineau `'coordinates'` is not currently a key? I'm not understanding. I would like for it to be a key so I can obtain the value associated with it but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `'coordinates' ` ***is*** a key in the first dictionary in the list associated with the key `'location'` in some undefined-in-your-question outer container dictionary. Please add a [mre] to your question and I will formally answer it.

Comment: @martineau I'm sorry I'm really not trying to be annoying, but how is it a key? It's within a list. When I  run your suggested code it doesn't work.

Comment: What part of my request to add a [mre] was unclear?

Comment: @martineau I answered before you edited. I edited it to include the entire data source now.

Comment: Sorry to say that what you added to your question isn't valid Python (or JSON) data. Please verify that it is before posting another update.

Comment: @martineau Can you give me a specific detail of what's wrong with the formatting? Len(List) reveals it is size one and I don't see a difference between my personal data and what I have written here.

Comment: When I put just what you have posted for the data into a script and run it there are errors. You can do this yourself which is what I meant about verifying it.

Comment: Ok I will try, thank you and sorry for the headaches. I am new at this but I'm sure that much is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following does what you want (although I'm not totally sure since I had to fix your input data to make it valid and guess a little on what exactly you wanted the result to be.

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [{'date': 'Aug 1 1980',
         'hour': '2PM',
         'group': {'location': [{'country': 'United States',
                                 'state': 'Utah',
                                 'city': 'St. George',
                                 'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}]}},
        {'date': 'Aug 1 1980',
         'hour': '4PM',
         'group': {'location': [{'country': 'United States',
                                 'state': 'Utah',
                                 'city': 'St. George',
                                 'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}]}}]

fixed_data = []
for dct in data:
    dct['group']['location'] = dct['group']['location'][0]
    fixed_data.append(dct)

pprint(fixed_data, sort_dicts=0)
```

Printed result:

```
[{'date': 'Aug 1 1980',
  'hour': '2PM',
  'group': {'location': {'country': 'United States',
                         'state': 'Utah',
                         'city': 'St. George',
                         'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}}},
 {'date': 'Aug 1 1980',
  'hour': '4PM',
  'group': {'location': {'country': 'United States',
                         'state': 'Utah',
                         'city': 'St. George',
                         'coordinates': [37.0965, 113.5684]}}}]
```